# Does removing elements from within jQuery.each mess up the loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, foreach

Let's say I do something like :

```
$('.item').each(function (index)
{
   if (index === 3)$(this).remove(); 
   else if (index === 4)$(this).remove();
});
```

Will this work or will I mess up the loop/indexes since I will be removing elements from an array while looping through it ?

Same question when adding :

```
$('.item').each(function (index)
{
   $(this).parent().append('<div class="item"></div>');
});
```

Will this create an infinite loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not it doesn't as you are removing the element only from the dom structure not from the jQuery object itself.

The jQuery obejct is not a live object like the [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) object returned by [getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).

So even though the element is removed from the dom, its reference is still present in the jQuery object which called the `each` method.